# How to cluster co-ordinates based on time?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, cluster-analysis, self-organizing-maps

I have a 7x6 grid in which an object moving is being tracked. The object can move randomly in any direction with any pace (can even come to a halt) within the grid.

Input: coordinates of the object every second are stored in a .csv file (x-coordinate, y-coordinate, ith second), where i=0 to n(n seconds of tracking).

Please, suggest a machine learning algorithm which can predict centroids of clusters of coordinates as mentioned in below output.

Output: Cluster centroids of points where the object came to halt (one after the other (c1,c2,c3,...,c8), named based on time as shown in below picture).

[image: Cluster centroids]

Answer (score 1):

Return the last position for each object.

That should satisfy your requirements, without any learning or clustering.

Comment: There is only one object here.

Comment: Then it appears I could not understand your question.